# Python Web Scripting

Tags: python, regex, web-crawler

I wanted to do this before for some websites but didn't know where to start. This time however I am adamant. I am talking about the scripts where we crawl a website and extract the data we require. My target is this: Basically I have to appear for job interviews in December. There is this site (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/) which contains large number of questions from previous interviews (like http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-set-42-on-campus/ & http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adobe-interview-set-6-campus-mts-1/). Every title has word "set" and a number in it. It is quite cumbersome to keep track of what I have done and what not. So I want to extract questions from each of these pages and put them in a pdf with the title. How can I do this using curl, regex and Scrapy? I am intermediate in C/C++/Java and but have only beginner proficiency in Python. Any help is much appreciated. Also point me to any such scripts you such know of. I want to do this on my own. Just requires a starting point and some guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want just a starting point, try `scrapy` a screen-scraping library for python. I would recommend that you use the `requests` library for making requests. It's by far the simplest option (with no loss of power).

Also, don't try to parse html or xml with a regex. Just don't. Use one of the fine libraries available (beautifulsoup or lxml, or lxml with a beautifulsoup backend are the most popular, but there are others).

Comment: Thanks. Also do I need to manually collect all the links I want my crawler to crawl?

Comment: @user1425223 Unless...there's a source for them. I'm not sure what else you would expect. You could automate that collection process probably.